# Кодировка memo \ DelphiXE

Tags: delphi, кодировка

Сделала небольшую программу для замены слов. На форме находится компонент Memo1 и кнопка.

То есть, если к примеру, текст в Memo вот такого плана в стандартной кодировке:

```
Слово1=замена
Слово2=замена
Слово3=замена
```

То замена слов не идет.

А если перевожу этот же текст в кодировку ANSI то есть вот так:

```
РЎР»РѕРІРѕ1=Р—Р°РјРµРЅР°
РЎР»РѕРІРѕ1=Р—Р°РјРµРЅР°
РЎР»РѕРІРѕ1=Р—Р°РјРµРЅР°
```

То программа отлично работает.

Как заставить *Memo1* автоматически определять кодировку?

Пробовала прописывать в коде Memo:

```
Memo1.Text := utf8ToAnsi(Memo1.Text);
```

Но понимаю что увы, но это далеко не то..

Замену делаю вот так:

```
s := StringReplace(s, frm_Main.ReplaceList[j][0], frm_Main.ReplaceList[j], indexR, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

Comment: а как вы замену-то делаете?

Comment: @teran, Делаю через функцию. Обновила вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Замена ведется в файлах? или в тексте который на форме? стандартная для Delphi XE кодировка Unicode(который из них не помню, но точно не UTF8)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, да замена ведется в текстовом файле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Var
  FileIn: TStringList;
begin
  // Если память выделить не удастся, то будет исключение
  FileIn := TStringList.Create;
  Try
    //Тут могут быть исключения, например файл отсутствует
    FileIn.LoadFromFile('FileName', TEncoding.FANSIEncoding);//<< Выбираете верную кодировку файла

    FileIn.Text := StringReplace(FileIn.Text, frm_Main.ReplaceList[j][0], frm_Main.ReplaceList[j], indexR, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);

    FileIn.SaveToFile('FileName', TEncoding.FANSIEncoding);//<< Выбираете НУЖНУЮ кодировку файла
  Finally
    FileIn.Free; //Святое, чистим память, за нас ее в делфи никто не почистит
  end;
end;
```

В результате будет замена в "родной" для Delphi кодировке, с возможностью сохранить в файл с нужной вам кодировкой

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83443/discussion-on-answer-by----memo-delphixe).

Comment: Проверку на nil перед вызовом Free делать не надо. Она уже содержится внутри функции Free.

Comment: @Kromster Да чтож вы про эту проверку =) посмотрите чат =) там указано зачем проверка, она не нужна если код создания находится вне блока Try, собственно всё объяснение к коду теперь болтается в чате =)

Comment: Повторюсь, проверка не нужна в любом случае, т.к. она содержится внутри метода Free. procedure TObject.Free;
begin
{$IFNDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
  if Self <> nil then
    Destroy;
{$ENDIF}
end;

Comment: Был не прав, уточню. Также не нужно делать присвоение nil и не нужно вызывать конструктор внутри try..finally, т.к. конструктор либо сработает и переменной будет присвоен объект, либо свалится и исключение не даст нам добраться до кода в finally

Comment: @Kromster, в таком исполнении кода как сейчас - проверка и присвоение не нужны. В первоначальном виде - нужны, и если вам видна история редактирование - посмотрите ее, все изменения были добавлены для доведения кода до абсурда количеством проверок. Изначально код был оставлен как пример одной функции, но "местные" гуру начали критику на тему отсутствия освобождения памяти и проверок, после чего и были такие изменения

Comment: Тут всего 2 варианта, либо приводить короткий код (три значащих строчки), либо весь (с Create-try-finally-Free). В любом случае, сейчас все хорошо, ловите плюс!